# Search a dataframe using another dataframe or RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have 2 dataframes in apache spark.

df 1 has the show number and descriptions... the data looks like

**show_no     | descrip** 
a           | this is mikey
b           | here comes donald
c           | mary and george go home
d           | mary and george come to town

and the second data frame has the characters

**characters**
george
donald
mary 
minnie

I need to search the the show description one to find out which shows feature which characters...

the final output should look like

**character | showscharacterisin**
george | c,d
donald | b
mary    | c.d
minnie | No show

these data sets are contrived and simple but it expresses the search functionality I am trying to implement. I basically need to search the text of 1 dataframe using the values from another dataframe.

This would be easy to do in a udf inside of sql server, I would basically loop through the show descrip each time and return the show no using a "contains" search on the description.

the problem I have is that I see no way to do this using a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you should further breakdown the first dataset so that show_no is mapped to each word in the description. 
For e.g first row could be broken down like

```
show_no | descrip
a | this
a | is 
a | mikey
```

2) You can filter out the stopwords from this if needed.

3) After this you can join it with "**characters**" to get the final desired output.

Hope this helps.
Amit